# Что такое "ходить капканами"?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Употребительно в Сибири, применяется в значении: блуждать, заблудиться, например:

> Ходили капканами пока не нашли указанный адрес

Есть идеи по-поводу этимологии выражения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, запутанный маршрут напоминает обход капканов, к которым время от времени наведываются. Их нельзя обойти по прямой, поскольку они расставлены на какой-то площади и расположены не по геометрическим законам (так бывает и с нумерацией домов). Видимо, иногда и по приметам приходится их искать.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, запутанный маршрут напоминает обход капканов, к которым время от времени наведываются. Их нельзя обойти по прямой, поскольку они расставлены на какой-то площади и расположены не по геометрическим законам (так бывает и с нумерацией домов). Видимо, иногда и по приметам приходится их искать.